# M2: Impossible finish reindex

Tags: magento2, reindex

Now all products are were gone on all store view. I checked and product and category index is proccessed.

I try reset indexes and reindex again but now I wait about 50 minutes and no result.

[image]

Any solution ?

Comment: Is it a live website?

Comment: yes, It is a live

Comment: Are you running the command after putting Magento in maintenance mode?